# Mapping tensors to operations in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to combine a number of tf.write_file ops into single op to save a batch of images **inside single Session.run() call**, with no luck.

This code:

```
r = tf.range(tf.shape(images)[0])
crops = tf.image.crop_and_resize(images, boxes, r, [160, 160])
crops = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(crops, dtype=tf.uint8)

def write_ith_image(i):
    nonlocal out_file_tensor, crops
    encoded_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(crops[i])
    return tf.write_file(out_file_tensor[i], encoded_image)

encode_all = tf.map_fn(write_ith_image, r)
```

results in:

```
TypeError: Can't convert Operation 'map/while/WriteFile' to Tensor (target dtype=None, name='value', as_ref=False)
```

`tf.while_loop` gives similar results. Is there a way to map a tensor to a group of operations that can be executed in single tf.Session.run() call? Why this works for tensors, but not for operations with side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a dummy value.

```
def write_ith_image(i):
    nonlocal out_file_tensor, crops
    encoded_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(crops[i])
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.write_file(out_file_tensor[i], encoded_image)]):
      dummy = tf.constant([0])
    return dummy

encode_all = tf.map_fn(write_ith_image, r)
```

Not pretty, but gets the job done.

You could get something slightly more satisfying with `tf.while_loop` (no dummy values), but it would be more verbose and probably not any more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, this works, tf.control_dependencies was the key. It's a shame there's no clean way to do this.